# My IF function isn't working when I try to pull out a specific word

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to have the cell populate if the word `CAT|I` is in a different cell. I am using the following function:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CAT|I,",F12)),"CAT I","NO")
```

Unfortunately it is showing up `CAT I` for all my `CAT|II` and `CAT|III` cells but `NO` for my `CAT|I`.

Comment: Please post some example data. Without knowing how your data exactly looks like, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: You should provide the sample file or screenshot about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove that comma it seems to work as intended:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CAT|I",F12)),"CAT I","NO")
```

[image]